# Grab all fieldset elements inside div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

In my ASP MVC 3 view I have a number of `fieldset` elements that are `hidden` when the page loads. Based upon a user selection of a group of radio buttons, I need to make the corresponding `fieldset` visible.

I'd like to do this in jquery by making an array of the `fieldset` elements, then cycle through them, adjusting their `visibility` property if they match the selected radio button or not. Is this possible?

Since there is so much code in the `fieldsets` I attached the screen shot below to save space/make it more readable. The `fieldsets` I am trying to alter are inside of the `RightDiv`. If you need any more detail, please let me know. Thx[image]

Comment: couldn't you provide a minimal working sample instead of posting picture???

Comment: As I said, I didn't post all the code to save space. It wouldn't help to be able to see every single `fieldset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, posted a bit too soon on this. Tried the following below and it worked just fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=TransactionType]').change(function () {
        var radioValue = $(this);
        var elements = [];

        $('#RightDiv').children().each(function () {
            elements.push($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('[name="TransactionType"]').change(function(){
       var id = '#' + this.className; //Get the id from the clicked radio classname
       $('#RightDiv').find('fieldset').hide();// hide all fieldsets;
       $('#RightDiv').find(id).show(); // show the selected one.
    });
});
```

Just note that in your html helper you are providing the the first overload as same name for all. All is well except i believe it will create duplicate ids for each of these. You may want to override it in the HTMLattributes.

```
@Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new{@class="Enroll", id="Radio1"}) 
@Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new{@class="New", id="Radio2"})
```